# composer update failed with "Failed to set PHP CodeSniffer installed_paths Config"

Tags: magento2, composer

New to magento

I wanted to upgrade my Magento to 2.4.4 .
Using php 7.4 with Ubuntu 20.04 and nginx

composer -vvv update

I get this:

```
Dependency resolution completed in 0.003 seconds
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
> post-autoload-dump: Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterPluginDelegator->onPostAutoloadDump
119 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> post-update-cmd: MagentoHackathon\Composer\Magento\Plugin->onNewCodeEvent
start magento deploy via deployManager
jump over deployLibraries as no Magento libraryPath is set
> post-update-cmd: Dealerdirect\Composer\Plugin\Installers\PHPCodeSniffer\Plugin->onDependenciesChangedEvent
Running PHPCodeSniffer Composer Installer
Executing command (/var/www/magento2/vendor/bin): phpcs --config-show
Executing command (/var/www/magento2/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer): '/usr/bin/php7.4' -d allow_url_fopen='1' -d disable_functions='' -d memory_limit='-1' ./bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
Failed to set PHP CodeSniffer installed_paths Config
```

so I go to the directory /var/www/magento2/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer and run the command '/usr/bin/php7.4' -d allow_url_fopen='1' -d disable_functions='' -d memory_limit='-1' ./bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility

I get:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/magento2/vendor/composer/../../app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/magento2/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/magento2/vendor/composer/../../app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php' (include_path='/var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/magento2/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59
```

clearly this is a path issue with my composer and I do not have any NonComposerComponentRegistration.php

How do I correct this path issue? should I just uninstall composer and reinstall it? hopefully this won't affect my magento install.

Comment: further to my investigation /app/bootstrap.php is missing with bunch of other files!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the vendor folder completely. Reset the permissions of all files. the sudo composer install and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

##### simple case:

From the `html` directory run `vendor/bin/phpcs --config-show`
If `installed_paths` is not listed, or is incorrect run the following:

```
vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
```

##### case with code or module issues:

If `vendor/bin/phpcs --config-show` shows no output there could be an error in a module or a deployment problem.
Run `phpdbg vendor/bin/phpcs --config-show`
At the prompt press `r`, capture the error, `quit`, and then correct the error.

For example, in the output below, I had a cached module that was incompatible with a pending update.  Removing the cached module cleared the error.

```
$ phpdbg vendor/bin/phpcs --config-show

[Welcome to phpdbg, the interactive PHP debugger, v8.1.27]
To get help using phpdbg type "help" and press enter
[Please report bugs to <http://bugs.php.net/report.php>]
[Successful compilation of /var/www/magento/html/vendor/bin/phpcs]

prompt> r

[Uncaught LogicException in /var/www/magento/html/vendor/magento/framework/Component/ComponentRegistrar.php on line 48: Module '<some module>' from '/var/www/magento/html/app/code/<cached module>]
>00050:                 . 'has been already defined in \'' . self::$paths[$type][$componentName] . '\'.'
 00051:             );
 00052:         }

prompt> quit

$ rm -rf app/code/<cached module>
$ phpdbg vendor/bin/phpcs --config-show
[Welcome to phpdbg, the interactive PHP debugger, v8.1.27]
To get help using phpdbg type "help" and press enter
[Please report bugs to <http://bugs.php.net/report.php>]
[Successful compilation of /var/www/magento/html/vendor/bin/phpcs]
prompt> r
Using config file: 

[Script ended normally]
prompt> quit

$ vendor/bin/phpcs --config-show
Using config file: 

$ vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
Using config file: /var/www/magento/html/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf

Config value "installed_paths" added successfully

$ vendor/bin/phpcs --config-show
Using config file: /var/www/magento/html/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf

installed_paths: ../../magento/magento-coding-standard,../../phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
```

Now `composer update` proceeds without this error.